# Behaviour of KafkaProducer when the connection to Kafka stream is broken

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I was expecting that KafkaProducer will throw timeout exception when the connection to brokers is broken (e.g. losing internet access, brokers is not available...), but from what I observed, KafkaProducer still performed the sending normally without any problem. (I set Ack to no).

I checked its documentation and there is no part about how the KafkaProducer will behave when the connection to brokers is broken/ restored.

Does anyone have experiences with this? I'm using Kafka version 0.10, with asynchronous send and handle error in callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I want to clarify that [*Kafka Streams*](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams) is Apache Kafka's stream processing library and your question seems not to be about Kafka Streams. You only talk about producer and brokers (just want to clarify terminology to avoid future confusion).

About your question: The only way to check if a write to a broker was successful is by enabling acks. If you disable acks, the producer applies a "fire and forget" strategy and does not check if a write was successful and/or if any connection to the Kafka cluster is still established etc.

Because you do not enable acks, you can never get an error callback. This in independent of sync/async writing.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I will update the terminology in the question as well

Comment: @Matthias, I have set ACKS_CONFIG = äll, but still i dint get any error/exception while kafka is down. Is there any other config I need to do. Please guide me for the same.

Comment: Not sure. Do you do sync/async writes? Did you set a send `Callback`?